# Does the value of std::endl depend on the OS?

Tags: c++, std

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what does std::endl represent exactly on each platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911018/what-does-stdendl-represent-exactly-on-each-platform)

I'm trying to figure out if std::endl returns `\r\n`, `\n`, or `\r` depending on the platform, or if it sticks with one all the time.

Comment: Thanks for that informational link. I did search for "value of std::endl" and that Q is not anywhere on the first 5 pages.  I'm sorry about the duplicate question, but due to the fact that the term `std::endl` is so prolific, I'm sure you can understand how it might be hard to search for.

Comment: No, no, I'm not pointing the accusing finger. The only way I got this result was using the word "platforms" alongside std::endl. I could easily see how one would fail to conjure up that particular phrasing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`std::endl` is just a "shorthand" for `'\n' << std::flush`. It is not platform dependent.

However, `'\n'` itself is handled differently on each platform and gets replaced with `'\r\n'`, `'\n'`, or `'\r'` (or something like that) if the stream is opened in text mode.

Comment: Or something very different.  If the system uses record oriented files, it might simply cause a new record to be started.  Unless, of course, the file was opened in binary mode.

Comment: +1 I had no idea that `\n` had any special meaning to C++. I always thought it was simply `0x0A` according to the **LF** character on the ASCII table.

Comment: Also std::endl flushes the buffer. `\n` does not flush the buffer which is a small performance benefit.

Answer (score 2):

'\n' Outputs a newline (in the appropriate platform-specific representation, so it generates a "\r\n" on Windows). std::endl does the same and flushes it.

Use '\n' instead of std::endl; when trying to output a newline, but use `std::endl` when trying to flush it. Unnecessary flushing decreases the performance of your application, for all we know file i/o is one of the slowest operations besides user i/o.

Comment: +1 for when to use `\n` vs `endl`

Comment: i think, if file i/o is a bottleneck, use something else than iostreams ;-) and just focus on readability. for that, `\n` may well be more readable than `endl`, but one problem is that ***it can be hidden inside strings***. so as a general convention i prefer `endl`. the flushing is just a nice side-effect, e.g. if a program crashes it's nice to have as much of the output as possible presented (and repeat, for efficiency use something other than iostreams, is my advice: efficiency is just an irrelevant argument here).

Comment: Unless you know that it's going to cause problems, use `std::endl`.  It sure makes things a lot easier to debug.

Comment: I was intrigued by this very question when I started learning C++ from "The C++ Programming Language" by Bjarne Stroustrup.. where he talks about `endl` and frequently uses `\n`. I first thought it could've been his habit from the C days, and I forced myself to actually ask him. This is his advice TBH.

Comment: For debugging purpose, one could also switch on line buffering.